# Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am working on a site that displays pictures accross the Y axis of the browser and spans about 12500px wide.

I am using the Hortizontal way as a base but I have just realized that the horizontal scrolling with both the arrows and the mouse's wheel does not work in both safari and chrome.

http://www.thehorizontalway.com/

Is there any way, preferably with Jquery, that I can do either:

a) place arrows that will scroll the window left to right upon clicking/hovering?

b) convert the users mouse's wheel scroll into a horizontal scroll?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I ended up using Jquery Tools's mashup of mouse scroll which supports horizontal scrolling in all browsers

Comment: This is a tutorial http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/14, which shows how to create a horizontal showcase using JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically scroll the window up, down, left or right using [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.scrollTo) or [`window.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scrollBy). Put these into the `click` or `mouseover` event handlers on whatever you want and it should do as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you...

http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding

You can increase the width to become your full width and position buttons absolutely e.t.c